# How do I call a remote web service from the context of a Plone object when a user clicks a CMF Action? Plone 4

Tags: action, plone

I am designing an integration process where my Plone 4 site can share objects and content with other systems when a user decides to publish an object to remote servers.  One of the first steps towards making this a reality is adding a "Remote Publish" CMF action off of an ATFolder for instance.  I did this in the portal_actions tool provided in the ZMI.  I set the URL expression to ${globals_view/getCurrentFolderUrl}/publish.

Now I understand that I need to register the action somewhere to get it to present a form that asks for the remote server address that handles the web service calls.  How do I build and send a POST REQUEST with the folder object's new properties and children when the user has clicked the new "Remote Publish" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split this problem to subproblems and solve each individually

**How to customize Plone**

http://developer.plone.org/getstarted/index.html

**How to add actions to content items**

https://developer.plone.org/functionality/actions.html

**How to create a form which asks for a remote server address and where you can program Python logic**

http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/schema-driven-forms/index.html and https://developer.plone.org/forms/z3c.form.html

**How to read folder and object content in Plone**

http://developer.plone.org/content/listing.html

http://developer.plone.org/content/archetypes/fields.html#accessing-archetypes-field-value

**How to create a POST request in Python**

http://docs.python-requests.org/

**How to make remote server to handle the incoming request**

[not part of the question]

Unless you do not have enough Python and Plone experience this is quite big question to tackle. To solve this problem  I suggest you create a new sub-question for every part and solve them independently.